# React ignore props changes in shouldComponentUpdate()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, react-native

Sometimes using PureComponent or Memo for FlatList items can be helpful in optimizing the flatlist performance but it can also cause more performance issues sometimes. It depends on the props that are being passed to the list item. If too many props are being passed to the list item then it can only worsen the performance.

In my use case, the main component of the list has a lot of properties so I need to implement my own shouldComponentUpdate function. As my props will not cause a re-render (an update), I need to ignore them in the shouldComponentUpdate (but not the state).

I have tried something like this:

```
 state = {
    count: 0,
    player: {
       name: "Nick"
    }
 } 


 shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return nextState !== this.state;
 }
```

But doesn't work, as nextState references the same memory as this.state (I think).

Any ideas how to do that?

(**Doing [this](https://codingislove.com/optimize-react-native-flatlist-performance/)** because I am following these tips **to get a better FlatList performance**). This is my FlatList:

```
 keyExtractor = ({ id }) => id; // each element in the data array has an unique uuid.

 <FlatList
    data={data}
    getItemLayout={this.getItemLayout}
    keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
    listKey={listKey}
    legacyImplementation={false}
    numColumns={1}
    renderItem={this.renderItem}
    initialNumToRender={10}
    windowSize={5}
    maxToRenderPerBatch={5}
    updateCellsBatchingPeriod={50}
    removeClippedSubviews={false}
    ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
    ListEmptyComponent={ListEmptyComponent}
    onEndReached={onEndReached}
    onEndReachedThreshold={0.15}
  />
```

Thank you.

Comment: This sounds so so so so so so so so wrong. You've arrived at the "solution" to your problem erroneously, could you describe what your **actual** problem is (performance?) and then you'll get a better answer

Comment: Look at point 8 https://codingislove.com/optimize-react-native-flatlist-performance/ I am following those tips for my FlatList and the only one that I do not comply with is that. For example, I have a property theme (from react-native-paper): {colors:  ....} which is a really long object, and I think that extending React.PureComponent with the shallow comparison can affect performance.

Comment: Yes, point 8 is valid - don't use `PureComponent` or `memo` when you have lots of props. But you have translated that to `make shouldComponentUpdate return false for everything except state changes` which is just wild.

Comment: But if shouldComponentUpdate is only called after the first render, why wouldn't be good to ignore the props?

Comment: For example, if the props received are never updated, why should I compare nextProps with the current component props (something that PureComponent do in its shouldComponentUpdate method)?

Comment: @Adam But not sure, I have less than a year with React.

Comment: Are you experiencing bad performance in a release build, or only in a development build? Also, have you set good `keys` (using `keyExtractor`)?

Comment: In development mode FPS for the JS Thread goes down to 3 when scrolling too fast. If not scrolling fast, between 40/50 FPS. In a minified production mode (not compiled), I get 17FPS (again for the JS Thread) when scrolling fast, and 50/60 when scrolling normal.

Comment: I have also checked my FlatList optimization properties (thought that was the problem) but seems to be good:  initialNumToRender={10}, windowSize={5}, maxToRenderPerBatch={5}, updateCellsBatchingPeriod={50}, removeClippedSubviews={false}  (2 items cover my full viewport). Pd: Performance issues comes when I fave +40 items in the list.

Comment: And yes, keyExtractor returns an uuid (the respective id of the item).

Comment: This this just requires debugging - strip out your complex component and replace it with a simple one and see if it renders fast. Then add pieces back in bit by bit and see when it starts to slow down.

Comment: @Adam After some hours looking for the error, I have decided to change my item to a simple view with a text. with 100 items, the FlatList performance was the same as with my other component. Then, I did shouldComponentUpdate() { return false; } just for testing purposes, and console.log("rendering") in the render() method of the new component. 
To my surprise, the components that are outside my viewport, and reappear on screen after scrolling, are rendered again, ignoring shouldComponentUpdate. Do you know if this is the expected behaviour?